# Solving a linear system of equations in Scilab

Tags: math, scilab

I want to solve the following system `Ax=b` where the dimensions of `A` are `m`,`n` `(m>n)`, `b` `m`,`1` and `x` `n`,`1`. After the solution under Scilab, I found that some components of my vector x are complex, I find that strange because I was told that the vector `x` must be real. How can you explain that?

Here is my code :

```
function [x] = sys_()
    [fid1,err1] = mopen("D:\Documents\sys_surdet\Donnees_test_A.txt","r");
    [fid2,err2] = mopen("D:\Documents\sys_surdet\Donnees_test_B.txt","r");
    A = mfscanf(-1,fid1,'%f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f %f');
    b = mfscanf(-1,fid2,'%f');
    A=10^(-A/10);
    b=10^(b/10);
    col = size(A);
    j = zeros(col(1,1),1);
    x = zeros(col(1,2),1);
    if rank(A)==col(1,2) then
        x=(A'*A)\(A'*b);
    else
        x=-1;
    end
    mclose(fid1);
    mclose(fid2);
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lines

```
A=10^(-A/10);

b=10^(b/10);
```

appear to be converting data from decibels back to standard units.
This is done on the entire vector or matrix at once similarly to Matlab, etc.
Did you confirm that the A and b are not complex-valued at this point?

```
x=(A'*A)\\(A'*b);
```

This is the standard normal equations for solving systems of equations with more equations than variables. It is (among other things) the least squares solution x. 
In SCILAB, you can get the same result with just

```
x=A\b;
```

This in general will be different from the solution

```
x=pinv(A)*b;
```

Your system of equations may be numerically close to singular (check for a singular value close to 0), or may have no solution.

In SCILAB, you can get more information about your system of equations with

```
cond(A'*A)
```

or

```
[x,kerA]=linsolve(A,-b);
```

See the SCILAB help section on linear algebra for more details.

Comment: thank you for your response. I did a SVD decomposition of my matrix, and i find that its singular values were close to 0 (approximately 0.1, sometimes 0.01). So I concluded that the matrix was the problem. But what I don't really understand is that my boss gave me a vector solution X which was obtained due to many measurements, and when I calculate the error AX-b i found that vector is a great solution and the error is really small. How can you explain that? Can a solution exist and couldn't be calculate with methods of scilab?

Comment: SCILAB uses BLAS and LAPACK, the standaerd Fortran libraries from the 1970s that are also used by Octave, Python Numpy and so on. So the results should be trustworthy, given a well-formed problem. Since for example Octave is open source, you  could install it, then try your same problem there and compare the results.

Comment: "Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes?" How ridiculous! SCILAB uses BLAS and LAPACK, the standard Fortran libraries that are also used by Matlab, Octave, Python Numpy and others. So the results should be trustworthy, given a well-formed problem. Singular values of .1 should not necessarily be small enough to throw off the solution. The singular values would presumably be 0 except for the noise/errors in the data. Try a QR decomposition to solve your system and see if there is any change.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what these are about:

```
A=10^(-A/10);
b=10^(b/10);
```

I'd solve this either by premultiplying both sides by A transpose and using LU decomposition and back substitution to solve for x (linear least squares) or Singular Value Decomposition (SVD).